# No flow rate in underfloor heating manifold

Tags: heating

I've recently fitted a Under Floor Heating system; a two room, four port manifold system.

I filled the system from the hose connection as directed (flowing water through the circuits until there are no air bubbles etc), checked pressure and so. I followed the instructional video which the supplier pointed me to with my order: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YKnpZh9fag)

I then connected the system to my central heating loop, and the pump is running (when required) and the actuators are firing, however there is no water flow according to the gauges at the top of the flow manifold.

So it looks like I'm not getting anyway water flow through the manifold. Is there anything obvious which could be the cause of this?

I have isolated the loops and turned on the drains out of the manifold and managed to get water to flow through the manifold from the flow line and out of the drain on the side of the manifold. So water is free to flow down the pipe, it just isn't for some reason.

Comment: Is there a bleeder valve above / near the circulation pumps?  If they aren't self priming you need to let all the air out of them too.

Comment: I've already bled them, no air is in them. It's as though water isn't getting to them

Comment: Is there no flow in any of the lines or just 1 or 2 that are not working?

Comment: @EdBeal there is no flow on any of the loops at the manifold. I can turn loops on or off in any combination, none show any flow.

Comment: Have you connected the 'end' of your UF loop to the 'return' or is it connected on the same line on the collector? (post a picture of the connection on the collector)

Comment: @DDS the return of each UFH loop goes to the return port of the relevant loop in the manifold. The flow is connected to the corresponding flow port of the manifold.

Comment: @Puffafish have you managed t solve your problem?

Comment: @Gellyke I kind of did a while later: there was a different valve at the thermalstore which had not been wired up (it had been left ready by my plumber but I had not been told about it)

Comment: @Puffafish I'm having the same problem, can you a picture of what not was wired up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I found the cause in the end: there was an extra automatic valve added between my thermal store and the UFH loop. Once I connected this to activate at the required time, hot water was received at the UFH manifold and all worked.